# Mixed data types in mongoDB document into spring-boot model

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a MongoDB database that has mixed data types. In some fields the data can be either a String array or just an array. When I try to map this documents into my spring-boot app it crashes and I suspect it is because of this mixed data types. What should I do to map this data correctly?

this is my model:

```
private List<Awards> awards;
    private String plot;
    private String[] genres; //This is the problematic field.
    private String[] cast;
    private String[] countries;
    private String[] directors;
    private String fullplot;
    private List<Imbd> imbd;
    private String[] languages;
    private String lastupdated;
    private int metacritic;
    private int num_mflix_comments;
    private String poster;
    private String rated;
    private Date released;
    private int runtime;
    private String title;
    private List<Tomatoes> tomatoes;
    private String[] writers;
    private int year;
```

and this is the error I get when trying to send a get to the endpoint:

```
Decoding into a 'Movie' failed with the following exception:

Failed to decode 'Movie'. Decoding 'genres' errored with: Can't find a codec for class [Ljava.lang.String;.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could decode the value into an Object, making the type of `genres` an `Object`. This way it allows to store simple Strings and arrays of Strings.

If you want to, you could create a customised getter, to always return a String array, also for a single String.

```
private Object genres;

public String[] getGenres() {
    if (genresinstanceof String) {
        return new String[]{(String) genres};
    } else if (genresinstanceof String[]) {
        return (String[]) genres;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Genres must be either a String or a String array.");
    }
}
```